# Unable to resolve conflicts while building AWX-EE custom image

Tags: python, ansible, dockerfile, ansible-awx

I'm currently building AWX EE custom image with the latest available but it seems latest versions got some conflicts with pip modules. My custom image was working great in July (awx-ee version 22.X 23.X)

I used to set collections/modules I need in requirements files as below. However, I got some conflicts with pip module I didn't set (so I assume there are "internal" or managed by AWX-EE base image) and I didn't know how to get rid off them.

I use ansible-builder for all of this task.

Here's my execution-environment.yml :

```
---
version: 1

build_arg_defaults:
  EE_BASE_IMAGE: 'quay.io/ansible/awx-ee:latest'

dependencies:
  galaxy: requirements.yml
  python: requirements.txt

additional_build_steps:
  prepend: |
    RUN cat /etc/os-release

  append:
   RUN whoami
```

Here's the content of requirements.yml

```
---
collections:
-  name: nutanix.ncp
-  name: community.hashi_vault
-  name: arubanetworks.aos_switch
-  name: community.general
```

and requirements.txt :

```
hvac
```

The error message I got is the following. I read some pip modules are in conflicts but I don't know where those modules have been configured/asked to be installed.
To get a workaround, I set hvac module to a very lower version than 1.2.X but error message is the same.

```
The user requested requests>=2.4.2 and ~=2.26.0
210.3     azure-core 1.28.0 depends on requests>=2.18.4
210.3     awxkit 13.0.0 depends on requests
210.3     hvac 1.2.1 depends on requests<3.0.0 and >=2.27.1
210.3
210.3 To fix this you could try to:
210.3 1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
210.3 2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict
210.3
210.3 ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts
------
Dockerfile:54
--------------------
  52 |     COPY _build/requirements.txt requirements.txt
  53 |     RUN $PYCMD /output/scripts/introspect.py introspect --sanitize --user-pip=requirements.txt --write-bindep=/tmp/src/bindep.txt --write-pip=/tmp/src/requirements.txt
  54 | >>> RUN /output/scripts/assemble
  55 |
  56 |     # Final build stage
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c /output/scripts/assemble" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

Also, I tried to remove azure-core cause I didn't need it ,directly in execution-environment.yml but it fails cause module isn't installed yet in the prepend part.

```
RUN python3 -m pip uninstall azure-core
```

About the solution provided by pip, **I don't know how I can loosen/remove a package version that I didn't ask for in my requirement file.**

```
210.3 1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
210.3 2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict
```

I also tried to set a requirements.txt empty but still got the same kind of error.

My question is : How can I set version of pip module that seems to be embedded in AWX-EE image ?

EDIT :
Finally found out the root cause : nutanix.ncp collection got a requirements.txt file that is responsible for asking  'requests'  ~=2.26.0

I'll try to override that or found a workaround.

**EDIT 2:**
After looking at ansible-runner debug and [execution-environment.yml](https://github.com/ansible/awx-ee/blob/devel/execution-environment.yml) it seems that this file is used because collections installed are exactly the same (+ those I set in my execution-environment.yml file) but I have no idea how to override it. (for instance, delete all azure_* collection which I don't need)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nutanix.ncp creates conflicts cause it's the only collection I use that specify python module version `requests~=2.26.0`

I finally create a new AWX-EE custom image without nutanix.ncp in requirements.yml => Building is ok.

And simply add nutanix.ncp as a requirements into my Ansible projects, collection is installed at project execution without any conflicts. Weird but working workaround.